# Changing label font size in a loop is not changing the size of the text

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uilabel

I have a view with 4 labels in it and sometimes it goes off the screen.

To avoid this, I am attemtping to change the size of the label text as follows:

```
while DefinitionAndExampleView.frame.maxY > view.frame.size.height {
    label1.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: (label1.font.pointSize - 1))
    label2.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: (label2.font.pointSize - 1))
    label3.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: (label3.font.pointSize - 1))
    label4.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: (label4.font.pointSize - 1))
}
```

However, this while loop keeps running and never terminates, because the point size of the 4 labels don't change.

Why are the point sizes of the labels not changing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that your labels don't go off the screen, you could set the adjustFontSizeToFitWidth to true. This way, your label text won't go off the screen, it will just change the size. Also, add constraints for the width to ensure that the width of the label will not expand.

`label1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`

Comment: Does not help - the label has multiple lines of text

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the maxY from DefinitonAndExampleView's frame, also there is a chance of frames only recalculate it size after a UI update. I would strongly recommend you to use constraints in your labels so that it wouldn't go off the screen. 
You can follow the official Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html) to get started at it.

Comment: Does not help - even trying without the loop and just executing the 4 lines of code once (as a test) does not make a difference

Comment: You don't need to change the size of your text, you just need to add [autolayout constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1) . You basically tells to the Interface that your labels can not surpass it's superview. You have to set your labels to be the size you want and set it's `Autoshrink` to `Minimum Font Scale`